# App signature for android and iOS in uber integration

Tags: android, ios, uber-api

I am developing an uber integration in my app and I realize that there is only one field for app signature. I have an Android and an iOS version and they don't share the same signature. So how could I develop the integration? Is there another way?

Answer (score 4):

You can add multiple app signatures on the dashboard. Once you enter your first one, an additional field will appear for you to add more. So you should be able add both your iOS and android app signatures